# How to check if an input is disabled with JavaScript in Selenium

Tags: javascript, input, selenium

I'm building and automated test script for a webapp using selenium and I'm trying to use the [waifForCondition](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#waitForCondition%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function of the API where it will wait until a JS script evaluates to `true`.

I currently have this source on the page:

```
<input id="modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0" type="text" name="modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0" readonly="" disabled="">
```

Which should change to:

```
<input id="modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0" type="text" name="modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0">
```

As soon as I put a certain value on another field and fire the "blur" event on it (and this field thus becomes "enabled").

And I'm trying to execute the following JS script to test when this field is enabled (basically what I found from "Googling"):

```
document.getElementbyId('modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0').disabled == false
```

However I'm getting a `SeleniumException` which indicates that "Object doesn't support this property or method". What can I do here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: p.s. checking for the `readonly` attribute would also work

Comment: are you using double equals to assign in your code? `disabled == false` ??

Comment: no, it is not an assignment, it is a check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking into this I found the answer. I'm documenting it here in case anyone has use for it.

I was running my question code in the FireBug console and it was working correctly; however when executing my script I kept getting `SeleniumException`.

It turns out that you need to use [`selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()`](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2010/03/selenium-rc-java-waitforcondition.html) for the RC to execute the JS script on the main window you're using instead of the control window that pops up.

As such, the JS code I actually need to evaluate ends up being this:

```
selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0').disabled == false
```

Which works just fine. Thanks for the other hints.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
document.getElementById('modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0').getAttribute('disabled') == false
```

You may need to set a variable and then check if it's set or null, so:

```
var isDisabled = document.getElementById('modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0').getAttribute('disabled')
```

then the condition becomes:

```
isDisabled == null || isDisabled == false
```

Comment: The log now shows the following error for the `SeleniumException`: "'doument.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object"

Comment: Simply using getElementById().disabled will always return `true` or `false`, there is no `null`. In cases like mine this is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Almost... you need:

```
if(document.getElementById('modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0').disabled == false){
  //                  ^- Capital "B"
  //it is not disabled
}
```

Comment: The `if` is supposed to be handled by selenium, I should just pass the function to evaluate. I had not seen the capital B thing though, I'll see how that works.

Comment: Capitalizing the `B` changed the Exception error to "Object Required".

Comment: I'm guessing this is failing because you are trying to get the "disabled" property of a null object reference.  are you sure this object with the id: `modifyHostsForm:idDnsIp0_0` exists?

Comment: Yes, I've isolated the object id using Bugzilla. on the same screen where this script is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you are checking `isDisabled == undefined`:

`isDisabled == null || isDisabled == false || isDisabled == undefined`